# How to do primary maths with cocoa and cocoa touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I'm quite new to xcode and am making a app where you put two numbers in to a text input and I don't know how to make xcode to do the adding sum, I tried this but it did not work

```
       self.answer.text = self.label.text + self.label2.text
```

Does anybody know how to do this.

Comment: Xcode is an IDE, that does not do arithmetic and all, it is objective-c and cocoa/ cocoa-touch frameworks that allows you to do so.

Comment: Cocoa is for OS X, Cocoa-Touch is for iOS. Choose between the iOS and Cocoa tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use :

```
NSInteger firstNumber=[self.label.text integerValue];
NSInteger secondNumber=[self.label2.text integerValue];
NSInteger total=firstNumber + secondNumber;
NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",total];

self.answer.text = string;
```

If you want to take double value replace `integerValue` with `doubleValue`

Comment: You can't set a string with an integer value, I suggest something like self.answer.text=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld",[self.label.text integerValue] + [self.label2.text integerValue] ];

Comment: I accepted but I am only new to stackoverflow and do not have 15 reputation

Comment: @Programer1038: now you have 15+

Answer (score 0):

Here is another interesting way:

```
//Some string with expression which was taken from self.label.text
NSString *s = @"2*(2.15-1)-4.1";
NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:s];
float result = [[expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil] floatValue];
NSLog(@"%f", result);
self.answer.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",result];
```